# How to limit the textarea length of each line in pixel, and number of line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I hope to set up a textarea, then people can select some fonts, for example, "sans-serif" and "serif" to type in the text into the textarea. I will set up to button such as button "sans-serif" and "serif" that if user click it, the textarea's font will change to relevant font.

But here are some conditions:

> 1. The maximum total line limit of the textarea is 4.
> 2. The maximum pixel of each line cannot more than 100px, 100px means characters that user input, not the textarea width.
> 3. If user types in on the line more than 100px of character, it will auto go to the next line.
> 4. When the user reaches to line 5, it will not allow user types in more.

I think it should be use html 5 canvas with javascript/ jquery. But because of I have a function is change the font of textarea. So do you have any idea?

Here are html and css setting:

HTML:

```
<textarea id="testarea"></textarea>
<br>
<div class="btn" onclick="$('#testarea').css('font-family', 'sans-serif');">Sans-serif</div>
<div class="btn" onclick="$('#testarea').css('font-family', 'serif');">Serif</div>
```

CSS:

```
#testarea{
  resize: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 232px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.45;
}
.btn{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So i have come up with a somewhat of a solution. Assumptions are made. Read full answer.

> 1. The maximum total line limit of the textarea is 4 - **Included**
> 2. The maximum pixel of each line cannot more than 100px, 100px means
>      characters that user input, not the textarea width. - **Included**
> 3. If user types in on the line more than 100px of character, it will
>      auto go to the next line. - **Included**
> 4. When the user reaches to line 5, it will not allow user types in
>      more. - **Included**

Which have been added.

> 1. JS - Not more than 4 lines (Max 4)
> 2. You have given the `font-size` in the `textarea` is `16px` therefore
>      `100/16 = 6.25`. The max characters per line i have taken is
>      `6`
> 3. More than 6 characters will go to the next line
> 4. Cannot type more than 4 lines

**Answer:**

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("testarea");
textarea.onkeyup = function() {
  var lines = textarea.value.split("\n");
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (lines[i].length <= 6) continue;
    var j = 0;
    space = 6;
    while (j++ <= 6) {
      if (lines[i].charAt(j) === " ") space = j;
    }
    lines[i + 1] = lines[i].substring(space + 1) + (lines[i + 1] || "");
    lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, space);
  }
  textarea.value = lines.slice(0, 4).join("\n");
};
```

```css
#testarea {
  resize: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 232px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.45;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="testarea"></textarea>
<br>
<div>
  <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Comic Sans</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="myFunction_2()">Reset</button>
</div>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("testarea").style.font = "italic bold 25px Comic Sans MS, Comic Sans MS, Comic Sans, cursive";
  }
</script>

<script>
  function myFunction_2() {
    document.getElementById("testarea").style.font = "italic normal 16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif";
  }
</script>
```

**Output Sample**

(Can type till next line or can press `Enter` and go to next line)
[image]

**Conclusion:**

Change accordingly to your requirement.

**Note:**

1. Code quality is not great, change accordingly.
2. This is assuming the
       `textarea` will have a fixed `font-size`
3. Changing the font when button is clicked will not be adjusted to the above requirement.

Have a great day.

Comment: it is a pretty good answer, but in my case, and use can see every font family make the text width is not same, for example, the examples font are not monospace. User input text such as "1", "A", even "日", will make the total width different.

Comment: Here is what I hope to use to measure the text in each line width in px: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_measuretext.asp

Comment: https://codepen.io/sctw/pen/RLWzRm this is what I do with px measuring. But cannot work with more than one line. And when change font, the last two character reached to more than 100px, I hope it to delete the last character.